# In Expression Engine 1.6, how do I disable caching for a specific page?

Tags: php, caching, expressionengine

In Expression Engine 1.6, how do I disable caching for a specific page? I'm working on tweaking a page, and it is annoying that after I make changes I am still seeing the cached copy. I don't want to turn off caching for the whole site because it gets a lot of traffic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about Template Caching (enabled per-template via the Template Preferences), I'd suggest that you not use that at all. It's advisable to use Tag Caching instead.

If you're talking about Tag Caching (i.e. adding `cache="yes" refresh="60"` to your exp tags), then I'd either:

- simply remove the cache tags from your page template (be it a global, generic page template, or a custom template you're using for this particular page), or;
- enable the setting to "Clear all caches when new entries are posted", so every time you save your entry, all caches are cleared. (See Admin » Channel Adminstration » Global Channel Preferences.)